# How can I switch on XML names?

Tags: android, xml

Okay, a general switch form is like:

```
switch (v.getId())
{
    case R.id.fifty:
        blablabla
        break;

    case R.id.button1:
        bla bla bla
        break;
}
```

My question is: Is there a way to check which XML file that id is in? So if it's in file1.xml that will be one case, and if it's in file2.xml that will be another case.

Comment: No - just make sure you make all of your resource ids unique right across your project.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can do it this way like below.

1. Ensure that you have assigned a Id to the root view (Top most view) of each XML.
2. Then switch on this Id in your activity code. You can get the id like below

   ```
   int rootId = findViewById(R.id.yourViewId).getRootView().getId();
   switch(rootId){
       case R.id.rootOfXML1: 
           doSomeThing(); 
           break;

       case R.id.rootOfXML2: 
           doSomeThingElse(); 
           break;
       .....

   }
   ```